# Query to order time events showing first future events and after show current events

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where i store events and it has 2 fields for dates. One for the start date (start_date) of the event and other for the end date (end_date). 
Some events dont have end_date defined or have end_date='1970-01-01'.

I used the following mysql query to retreive the current and future events.

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE start_time >= CURDATE() 
    OR (start_time <= CURDATE() AND end_time>=CURDATE()) 
ORDER BY events.start_time;
```

What i would need is a query that returns the same results but ordered in a different way and according to the following way:

- the events are 'divided' in two groups: the current events, and the future events. Current events are considered all the events that started in the day before the actual date ('yesterday') and still didn't finished.
- the results will show first future events, ordered ascending by start_time, and after show current events, ordered ascending by start_time.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `start_time <= CURDATE() AND ` - that's self evident based on the boolean just before it So no need to make the database check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
       DATEDIFF(start_time, CURDATE()) AS diff
FROM   events
WHERE  start_time >= CURDATE()
        OR ( start_time <= CURDATE()
             AND end_time >= CURDATE() )
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN diff > 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          end,
          diff ASC;
```

Comment: it seemd to be solved (: i'll do some more tests and if everything ok i will accept the answer.many thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY 
  (CASE WHEN start_time < CURDATE() AND end_time >= CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC,
  start_time ASC
```